# How to preserve file order in Ant concat?

Tags: ant

How to preserve file order in Ant concat?

Simple concat with fileset & includesfile produces rather "random" order, as order is not guaranteed:

```
<concat destfile="C:/targetdir/concatenated.file">
    <fileset dir="C:/sourcedir/">
        <includesfile name="C:/targetdir/includes.file" />
    </fileset>
</concat>
```

What I need is concatenation in specific order that the files are listed in the includes file.

So far I've found **resourcelist**, which should preserve order, but I can't seem to be able to produce any concatenated file with it. :/

```
<concat destfile="C:/targetdir/concatenated.file">
    <resourcelist>
        <file file="C:/targetdir/includes.file"/>
        <filterchain>
            <striplinecomments>
                <comment value="#"/>
            </striplinecomments>
            <prefixlines prefix="C:/sourcedir/"/>
        </filterchain>
    </resourcelist>
</concat>
```

Plus, the resourcelist can't seem to handle rows like

```
LibraryX/A/Stuff/Morestuff/*
```

Instead the row just produces a ".../Morestuff/* does not exist." -error

Includes file has list of relative paths:

```
LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileA.txt
LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileB.txt
LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileC.txt
LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileY.txt
```

Comment: What order do you expect to be implied by the wildcard `*` in `LibraryX/A/Stuff/Morestuff/*`?  Also, when you try the concat, what happens - silently does nothing?  Or some specific error?

Comment: For wildcards, the order is not important. There are certain things for every project that should be in the beginning of the concatenated file. The concatenation with the resourcelist doesn't seem to do anything, even if I remove the offending lines.. :/

Answer (score 13):

I was able to get a filelist working pretty easily:

```
<concat destfile="C:/targetdir/concatenated.file">
    <filelist dir="C:/sourcedir/">
        <file name="i.txt" />
        <file name="n.txt" />

        <file name="o.txt" />
        <file name="r.txt" />
        <file name="d.txt" />
        <file name="e.txt" />
        <file name="r.txt" />
    </filelist>
</concat>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This does not allow wildcards.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Ant 1.7+, you can use the sort command

```
   <concat destfile="C:/targetdir/concatenated.file">
        <sort>
            <fileset dir="C:/sourcedir/">   
                <include name="C:/targetdir/*.file" />                      
            </fileset>            
        </sort>            
   </concat>
```

You can find the documentation of sort [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#rcmp.content)

Answer (score 3):

[On Ant 1.8.2+] You can also pass the fileset via a sort, and sort on filename, like below:

```
<concat destfile="./${dir.publish}/${dir.js}/b.main-${build.number}.debug.js">
     <sort xmlns:rcmp="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.comparators">
          <fileset dir="./${dir.publish}/">
              <include name="**/${dir.js.main}/**/*.js"/>
              <exclude name="**/${dir.js.main}/**/*.min.js"/>
          </fileset>
          <rcmp:name />
     </sort>
  </concat>
```

Couple of things to watch out for:

1. Directories are sorted before files
2. Capitals come before lowercase

UPDATE:  Another alternative if you need to manually specify order:

```
<!-- create a ordered list of all the build files so that CIAPI & CIAPI.widget are built first  
    (can't find a smarter way to do this, since ant filesets are unordered) -->
<fileset id="a" dir="."><include name="CIAPI/build.project.xml"/></fileset>
<fileset id="b" dir="."><include name="CIAPI.widget/build.project.xml"/></fileset>
<fileset id="c" dir=".">
    <include name="**/build.project.xml"/>
    <exclude name="CIAPI/build.project.xml" />
    <exclude name="CIAPI.widget/build.project.xml" />
</fileset>
<union id="all_build_files">
    <fileset refid="a"/>
    <fileset refid="b"/>
    <fileset refid="c"/>
</union>
```

Ugly, but, erm, this is ant?

Answer (score 0):

try this, put in alphabetical order

```
<project name="concatPath" default="full">
<target name="full">
    <fileset id="fs" dir="./files" />
    <pathconvert refid="fs" property="concatList" pathsep=";" targetos="unix"/>
    <echo>${concatList}</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

this can be used with hierarchical structure of directories, and the order will be the exposed by David.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that XML is not order-dependent, by definition.

To concatenate files in a sorted order, consider using `<replace>` instead.

Create an order file that defines the order. Then, in your build file:

1. Copy the order file to the destination file with `<copy>`
2. Concatenate your files together into a temporary file with `<concat>`
3. Load the files into properties with `<loadfile>`
4. Insert the text from those files into the destination file with `<replace>`

Example order file *order_file.txt*:

```
    FILE_A_HERE
    CONCAT_FILES_HERE
```

Example ant build file *build.xml*:

```
    <copy file="order_file.txt" tofile="destination.txt" overwrite="yes">
    <concat destfile="tempfile.txt">
        <fileset dir="includes/">
            <include name="*.txt">
            <exclude name="fileA.txt">
        </fileset>
    </concat>
    <loadfile property="fileA" srcFile="includes/fileA.txt" />
    <loadfile property="concatFile" srcFile="tempfile.txt" />
    <replace file="destination.txt" token="FILE_A_HERE" value="fileA" />
    <replace file="destination.txt" token="CONCAT_FILES_HERE" value="concatFile" />
```