# How to to control the order of merge in Ant file

Tags: ant

I have this code which takes all the files in the folder **collection** and merges them with the covers.js file. The problem is there are 2 files inside of collections that need to be merged below covers.
But possibly I may want to control the order of how the files are being merged from the collection
folder. IS there a dependency attribute I can use.

```
<target name="merge box">
    <echo>${box.file}</echo>
    <concat destfile="${box.file}" fixlastline="yes" append="no">
    <fileset dir="${js.src.dir}/components/covers/" includes="**/*.js"/>
    <fileset dir="${js.src.dir}/collection/" includes="**/*.js" excludes="base.js"/>
    </concat>
</target>
```

**Update**
I also tried this but still doesn't work.

```
      <fileset dir="${js.src.dir}/collection" >
           <includesfile name="Templates.js" />
            <includesfile name="popup.js" />
            <includesfile name="popup-extend.js" />
        </fileset>
```

**Latest Update**

Tried this and it works but it doesn't hold the order of the include files.

```
<target name="merge box">
<echo>${box.file}</echo>
<concat destfile="${box.file}" fixlastline="yes" append="no">
<fileset dir="${js.src.dir}/components/covers/" includes="**/*.js"/>
<fileset dir="${js.src.dir}/collection" >
      <include name="Templates.js" />
      <include name="popup.js" />
      <include name="popup-extend.js" /> 
    </fileset>
    </concat>
</target>
```

popup-extend is meant to be merged below the popup code but its not doing that matter what order I put them in it will always put it in this order.

Templates
popup
popup-extend

The order I'm trying to get it in is

Templates
popup-extend
popup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<target name="merge box">
    <echo>${box.file}</echo>
    <concat destfile="${box.file}" fixlastline="yes" append="no">
        <fileset dir="${js.src.dir}/components/covers/" includes="**/*.js"/>
        <fileset file="${js.src.dir}/collection/Templates.js" />
        <fileset file="${js.src.dir}/collection/popup.js" />
        <fileset file="${js.src.dir}/collection/popup-extend.js" />
    </concat>
</target>
```

Or look here: [How to preserve file order in Ant concat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856522/how-to-preserve-file-order-in-ant-concat)

Comment: Thank you that made me grow a few gray hairs.